# selecting from two tables on mysql

Tags: php, mysql, select

I am trying to insert values by selecting from two different tables last inserted values. This code should work but it gives me error in 'SELECT MAX(users.id). I am sure have spelled right. What else can be wrong?

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO post(postid, userid,  readornot)
            SELECT MAX(post.postid), SELECT MAX(users.id), 
            :readornot FROM post, users  ";     
$select1 = $db->prepare($query1); ':readornot' => $readornot ));
```

Comment: For one thing, you can't bind columns/tables.

Comment: @jeroen they are trying to bind a column here, right? Edit: you keep deleting your comments *lol!*

Comment: @Fred-ii- No, I think it's just a value that gets inserted in `readornot`

Comment: @jeroen  ok. it seemed like it to me.

Comment: @jeroen I hear ya. Well, now seeing the answer below; the OP seems go have missed `VALUES` for one thing.

Comment: By the way, trying to insert `MAX(postid)` as `postid` from the table `post` in the table `post` is bound to lead to problems if that is the primary table index.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` is fine but the second `SELECT` would have to go and I don't know what values that join would give... Better stick with the answer below.

Comment: @jeroen TBH, I'm not very good at those types of queries since I've never had to deal with those. Let's see what the OP has to say about that answer, or if we'll see a green tick next to it ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hmmmm, `post.postid` sounds like a primary key or unique at the very least so I doubt this problem can be solved....

Comment: @jeroen The OP isn't responding to comments nor the answer given below. Maybe they left, that I don't know. So, it's anybody's ballgame/guess, *I guess*. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO post(postid, userid,  readornot)
           VALUES (
            (SELECT MAX(post.postid) FROM post) p, 
            (SELECT MAX(users.id) FROM users) u, 
            :readornot  
              )";     
$select1 = $db->prepare($query1); ':readornot' => $readornot ));
```

something like this, i think

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. But now I get the error message 'You can't specify target table'

Comment: I did not notice before: you are selecting from the same tabel (post) as where you are inserting into. Mysql does not like that.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what you are storing in your table. What are you trying to store (why, not technically how you try it)

Comment: I am trying to give a value which will not allow the user to do something.

Comment: I think I am going to make seperate queries and make a variable of the results.